# Com quais arquivos deve-se usar a tag <link> com BootStrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou estudando sobre o [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) e tenho uma dúvida: com quais arquivos deve-se usar a tag `<link>`? São todos os arquivos ou apenas alguns arquivos específicos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas estes devem servir :

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Com isso você faz referência não só do bootstrap css, assim como o tema que você poderá fazer uma sobrecarga, mas também o arquivo js que permitirá o uso de funções javascript!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode incluir apenas o *bootstrap.min.css*, o *bootstrap-theme.min.css* é opcional, para caso queira aproveitar alguns estilos de um tema padrão ou para caso queira editar ele e criar um tema customizado.

OBS: Caso você instale via bower ou clone o repositório, você tem a opção de usar LESS e incluir apenas os arquivos referentes aos modulos que esteja usando.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Diego Lopes Lima consegui utilizar o mecanismo.